# Identify darkest color that occurs noncontigously in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am looking for a way to identify the dark grey ovals on this example image:

[image]

I know I can find the darkest color in the image with a simple `min`. However, I am not interested in identifying the black in this example (darkest, contiguous part of the image). Therefore, I think my problem can be described: identifying the darkest color in the image that occurs *noncontigously*. That is, the dark grey ovals in the example above. I would appreciate your help. Notice how there's some noise also in the image, that I would ideally not take into account when find this darkest noncontiguous color. However, that might be different step/too much for this question.

I've been messing with output from `regionprops` to achieve this goal. However, I am not sure how to combine that output with color data. I was wondering if there is some MATLAB tool, or some image processing trick that would make this task easier.

Thanks in adavnce!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are steps you need to take to extract darker ovals from the image you provided:

1. Import the image
2. Turn it to black and white so you call `regionprops` and extract shape properties
3. Select the regions by their properties
4. Find the darkest color from selected regions

```
clc; close all; clear variables;
% import the image
I = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('KtzM7.png')));

% convert the image to balck and white
BW = (1-I)>0.05;

% extract shape and intensity properties of 
% connected components
stats = regionprops(BW, I, 'MinorAxisLength', ...
    'MajorAxisLength', 'Area', 'MeanIntensity');
% filter components by theis extend and area
ratio = [stats.MinorAxisLength] ./ [stats.MajorAxisLength];
[~, circleLike] = find((ratio > 0.65) & ([stats.Area] > 30));

% extract regions of interest in the image
L = bwlabel(BW);
RoI = ismember(L, circleLike);

% find the lowest intensity among RoI
intensities = [stats.MeanIntensity];
darkest = min(intensities(circleLike));

% remove non-RoI regions from output
O = max(I, 1-RoI);

% remove components that their intensity is not 
% equal to darkest color
O(abs(O-darkest)>0.1) = 1;

subplot 221, imshow(I), title('Input Image')
subplot 222, imshow(BW), title('Black & White')
subplot 223, imshow(RoI), title('Region of Interest');
subplot 224, imshow(O), title('Output Image')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering! This is very helpful. You answered my question described above. If you are feeling more generous, might you consider how to solve this problem in the event that the shapes cannot be clearly separated because of a more noisy background (i.e. one cannot use the the image `BW` from above).

Answer (score 1):

If the expected range/tones of grey to be extracted is known image thresholding can be applied to eliminate all the bodies that are not of that unique colour/tone. Here I converted the image to `greyscale` and filtered out the noise in the image using a median filter.

**Image 1:** `Lower_Threshold`: 125  and `Upper_Threshold`: 240

[image: Colour Shape Detection 1]

**Image 2:** `Lower_Threshold`: 20 and `Upper_Threshold`:160

[image: Colour Shape Detection 2]

```
  File_Name = "Ovals.png";

    Image = imread(File_Name);
    Greyscale_Image = rgb2gray(Image);
    
    %Filtering out some noise%
    Filtered_Image = medfilt2(Greyscale_Image, [10 10]);
    
    [Image_Height,Image_Width,Depth] = size(Image);
    
    Lower_Threshold = 125;
    Upper_Threshold = 140;
    
    
    %Thresholding the signal%
    for Row_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Height
       for Column_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Width 
        
        Pixel_Value = Filtered_Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner);
        if(Pixel_Value > Upper_Threshold)
        Filtered_Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner) = 255;    
        end
        
        if(Pixel_Value < Lower_Threshold)
            Filtered_Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner) = 255;    
        end
        
       end
    end
    
    Filtered_Image = medfilt2(Filtered_Image, [10 10]);
    imshow(Filtered_Image);
```

**Additional Sobel Edge Detection:**

Lowering the `Upper_Threshold` can filter out more data that is not of interest.

[image: Edge Detection]

```
File_Name = "PCA_Image.png";
Image = imread(File_Name);
Greyscale_Image = Image;

[Image_Height,Image_Width,Depth] = size(Image);

Lower_Threshold = 0;
Upper_Threshold = 50;

%Thresholding the sig6al%
for Row_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Height
   for Column_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Width 
    
    Pixel_Value = Greyscale_Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner);
    if(Pixel_Value > Upper_Threshold)
    Greyscale_Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner) = 255;    
    end
    
    if(Pixel_Value < Lower_Threshold)
        Greyscale_Image(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner) = 255;    
    end
    
   end
end

Binary_Image = Greyscale_Image < 255;
Edge_Image = edge(Greyscale_Image,'sobel');


subplot(1,2,1); imshow(Binary_Image); 
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Edge_Image);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The grey is not of known value. It could be darker or lighter. I am looking of a more dynamic approach. [here](https://imgur.com/INR7mX7) is a more realistic example. It's a PCA transformation of a skin lesion. I would like to find those darker areas, but not the ones that are super dark that only happen once.

Comment: If the range of grey you wish to extract is known the above method may still work. Though this is a tougher image to process on I'll take a look. Would you happen to know the range of dark values you wish to identify or is that on a per-basis depending on the image?

Comment: Extracting a histogram can be an additional step for finding/evaluating a range if hardcoded the range is not an option.

Comment: Yep, it depends on the image. That's why I'm trying to keep it general (darkest, non-contiguous color). Good idea with the histogram. But I think I will have to include some form of shape analysis, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Including shape analysis would provide better results for sure. That is a problem that may require smaller steps to solve. Could borderline fall into AI territory.

Comment: I see your edit. Looks like you highlighted the entire lesion. I'm looking for those dark spots scattered within the lesion. This is an example [binary mask](https://imgur.com/wk0sWRD) for that image. Thanks again for responding!

Comment: This is sure one tough task. I added some edge detection to my answer that may or may not be interesting to look into. Unfortunately, I was unable to get exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: That is very interesting. I actually was trying strictly edge-detecting methods before considering color-based methods now!

Comment: You can replace those nested loops with `Greyscale_Image((Greyscale_Image<Lower_Threshold)|(Greyscale_Image>Upper_Threshold))=255`.

Comment: @saastn Awesome catch. Sometimes forget this isn't C code.